# How to call a custom post with get_posts() instead of query_posts()?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I currently use `query_posts` to show these custom posts but I'm pretty sure that I should uses `get_posts()` to write it correctly.

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'type-mario' => 'games', 'showposts' => 10 ) ); ?>
<p>Mario games</p>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
 </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi **Elium2009**:

Using your code, I think this is what you were looking for? (note that `WP_Query()` is just the more direct version of `get_posts()`):

```
<?php $posts = WP_Query(array( 
   'taxonomy' => 'type-mario'
   'term' => 'games',
   'posts_per_page' => 10 
)); ?>
<p>Mario games</p>
<?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: THX !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Elium2009 - Welcome. :)

Comment: new WP_Query(array(

Answer (score 0):

You can use either really, but if you want to use get_posts this is how it's done:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=games&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to get it from my custom taxonomy associate to my custom-post, here type-mario is my taxonomy associate ton a custom-post and games his term.
How would you do that ?

Comment: Did you try to add the tax and term in the above code?`<?php query_posts('post_type=games&posts_per_page=10&taxonomy=type_mario&term=games'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: From the documentation for `query_posts`: `Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes.`